# Get item count in a list with filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, ajax

I have a list called "Users" and I need to retrieve the item count using .ajax from that list. For example, where "FirstName" == "James".

This is my request:

```
$.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Users/$count?$filter=((FirstName eq 'James'))",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);              
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

This way I get an error "Unsupported Media Type".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is $count return a plain text not a json so you call should be change from:

```
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
```

To

```
headers: { "Accept": "text/plain;odata=verbose" }
```

A full example:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MuroRespuesta/$count?$filter=((PreguntaID eq '5'))",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "text/plain;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);              
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Hope be Helpful

Comment: Thanks, @Marco, this solution is a lot faster than mine :)

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SharePoint online, try this REST endpoint.
Try below code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Users')/items?$filter=FirstName eq 'James'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d.results.length);              
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```